# A-star implementation with no path finding

Tags: artificial-intelligence, a-star, heuristics

I'm dealing with a task from the ai class that is the following

I need to use the A* algorithm

I have an n-digits display between 0-9

Every digit is identified with Ci, I=0...n-1

Under every digit there is a button that the agent can press to modify their value.

Every time the agent presses the button, digits change following 2 rules

1. Ci = (Ci+1)%10
2. C (I+j)%n = [C (I+j)%n +k]%10

Rule 1) is known to the agent while rule 2) isn't. Constants j and k are unknown to the agenti

My goal is to reach a goal-state starting from a 00...0 Configuration.

The goal-state can be generated applying random actions by the agent, aka pressing buttons randomly, so I'm sure there is at least one way to solve the problem.

My difficulties are:
How do I represent an n-digits display as a node?
How do I choose a right heuristics?
I'm stuck and frustrated with this exam.

(Sorry for English mistakes, I'm italian!)

Comment: I guess C(i+j)%n should be C((i+j)%n), that is you take the modulo n of the resulting index

Answer (score 0):

An A* algorithm is characterized namely by:

- The nodes forming the search tree.
- The definition of the "neighbor" concept.
- The definition of an optimistic heuristic for a node.

## Nodes in the search tree

As you are putting the problem, it seems that each node of the search tree is a configuration of the *n* digits of the display. Note that this can be easily represented as an array of integers of size *n*, where each position of the array represents a digit in the display, and the value represents the actual value of the digit in the display. For example, if a display of 5 digits showing `25847` could be represented by `[2, 5, 8, 4, 7]`. Easy, right?

## "Neighbor" concept

That is, how do yo change the display status? As you said, you can only use one of the *n* buttons below each digit. So, for every status, you will have exactly *n* possible "neighbors", or "descendants", if you think on the search tree. You will need a function that gives you the node resulting of pressing a particular button (which would simulate the agent pressing the button). Something like the following (in Java):

```java
static int[] pressButton(int[] node, int button, int j, int k) {
    int n = node.length;
    int[] newNode = Arrays.copyOf(node, n);
    newNode[button] = (newNode[button] + 1) % 10;
    newNode[(button + j) % n] = (newNode[(button + j) % n] + k) % 10;
    return newNode;
}
```

Now you have this, you can generate every child of the current node with something as simple as:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < node.length; i++) {
    int[] newNode = pressButton(node, i, j, k);
    // compute heuristic of the new node
    // add it to the A* priority queue
}
```

## Optimistic heuristic

Now you just need an heuristic that provides an optimistic estimation of the distance from a given node to the goal. One simple idea would be to assume that, for a given node, you will have to press the buttons at least as many times as the number of digits that differ from the goal; for example, if the goal is `41243` and the current node is `37253`, you will have to press a button at least three times, because there are three digits that differ from the goal. In Java:

```java
static int heuristic(int[] currentNode, int[] goal) {
    int h = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < goal.length; i++) {
        if (goal[i] != currentNode[i]) {
            h = h + 1;
        }
    }
    return h;
}
```

Note, however, that this heuristic is **wrong**. For example, if the goal is `81730`, your current node is `71230`, *j* = 2 and *k* = 5, this heuristic would give a value of 2; however, we could reach the goal state from the current node in just 1 step pressing button one, so the heuristic would be pessimist in this case. This is because each time a button is pressed, two digits are affected, which could make as get to the solution faster than we thought. To avoid this, we could just substract one from the heuristic (if it is bigger than one):

```java
static int heuristic(int[] currentNode, int[] goal) {
    int h = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < goal.length; i++) {
        if (goal[i] != currentNode[i]) {
            h = h + 1;
        }
    }
    if (h > 1) {
        h = h - 1;
    }
    return h;
}
```

More accurate heuristics could be defined based not only on the number of digits that differ from the goal, but also on how much they differ (the bigger the difference, the more times you need to press the button); however, I don't think there is an easy way to define an optimistic heuristic based on this (specially keeping in mind corner cases like *j* = 0 or *j* = *n*, negative *k*, etc.). If you are allowed to use the values of *j* and *k* in your heuristic (which I assumed not, because that's what I interpreted when you said that these are unknown to the agent), maybe there could be room for some sophistication, but even then, I would have a hard time trying to define it.

Finally, given the nature of the problem, it's very easy to reach already visited states when going from one node to another. If you want to keep your tree as an actual tree (and finite), and not as an infinite graph, you will have to use a set of already visited nodes, to avoid creating cycles in the search space.